# NetworkOnMainThreadException when parsing xml from server

Tags: android, exception, xml-parsing

I want to parsing Xml from server, but it take long time and finaly throws NetworkOnMainThreadException.
I have using strict mode, but it still thows NetworkOnMainThreadException.

**Update :
I try run aplication on emulator,this exception not show.
this exception show when i run aplication on real device.**

this my code to parsing xml :

```
public class ParsingXML extends Thread{
            //private Context ctx;
    private int status;
    private String raw_url;
    Context mctx;
    public DefaultHandler getMyExampleHandler() {
        return myExampleHandler;
    }
    DefaultHandler myExampleHandler=null;

    public ParsingXML(Context ctx , int status){
            //this.ctx=ctx;
            this.status=status;
            this.mctx=ctx;
            if(status==constant.GET_LIST_PRODUCT){
                raw_url=constant.URL+"listBarang.php";
            }
    }
    public ParsingXML(Context ctx,int status,String id){
        this.status=status;
        this.mctx=ctx;
        if(status==constant.GET_DETAIL_PRODUCT){
            raw_url=constant.URL+"detailBarang.php?id="+id;
        }
    }
    public void parse(){    
        try {
                StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
                StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
                URL url = new URL(raw_url);

                SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
                SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
                XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();

                if(status==constant.GET_LIST_PRODUCT){
                    myExampleHandler = new ListProductHandler();
                }
                else if(status==constant.GET_DETAIL_PRODUCT){
                    myExampleHandler = new DetailProductHandler();
                }
                xr.setContentHandler(myExampleHandler);

                xr.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(mctx, "Connection Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
                /* Display the TextView. */
    }
}
```

someone can help me please??
any help very apreciated. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include your network connection and parsing data to and from different server activities in a separate background thread. There is a class call `AsyncTask` to do this. Include your XML reading code snippets in the `doInBackground()` method. After reading all XML file you can show the result in `onPostExecute()` method.

Using the Thread class is deprecated. This is the [link to documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for more details. This process will get rid you from the `NetworkOnMainThreadException` .

Comment: Your update saw later. I guess you are running your code in a device that is higher than platform 3. It will give you `NetworkOnMainThreadException` when you are not using background thread for Internet connectivity.

Comment: I meant don't use Thread class, instead use `AsyncTask` class. And do all your background tasks like parsing XML in the `doInBackground` method.

Answer (score 0):

although you extend the thread, but your method `parse` also dont run in thread way, please put the `parse` method in `run` method, for example:

```
public void run(){
    parse();
}
```

Comment: But it throws new Exception :An error occured while executing doInBackground(). is it posible when start that thread on Asynctask???because i start parsing thread on AsyncTask.

Comment: and also this exception : WindowManager(3494): Activity com.portalshop.zendy.ListProductLama has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40821138 that was originally added here

Comment: `doInBackground` mean another thread not the ui thread, your exception maybe like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850573/activity-has-leaked-window-that-was-originally-added